# str.length; (vs) str.length()

Tags: java, methods, string-length

**I had a cannot find symbol error when I used length() for a string inside a function and got rid of it when i used length. I need to know what is the reason for this?**

code:

```
//this got cannot find symbol error
static int[] matchingStrings(String[] strings, String[] queries) {
        int n=queries.length();
        int ns=strings.length();
        int res[]=new int[n];
//this ran 
static int[] matchingStrings(String[] strings, String[] queries) {
        int n=queries.length;
        int ns=strings.length;
        int res[]=new int[n];
```

Comment: There is no method `length()` for an array (hence that symbol isn't found) but there is a property `length` (hence that works).

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/length-vs-length-java/

Comment: isn't str.length() a method for Strings?

Comment: Yes but you have an array here, not a string.

Comment: Get length of queries array: `queries.length` - Get length of first string inside of queries array: `queries[0].length()`

Comment: Note that `length` is an attribute for `String[]` (and arrays in general), but a method `length()` for `String`, because otherwise it would not be confusing enough.

Comment: got it @CherryDT Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused:

For array: `array.length;`
For Strings: `string.length();`

For arrays, length is not considered a method, it is a constant (an attribute)(that's why there is no ()).